# What is the point of wrapping JavaScript statements in parentheses?

Tags: javascript, parentheses

I have discovered that wrapping different statements in parentheses will return the last one:

```
(34892,47691876297,2000)                => 2000
('test',73,document.createElement('p')) => <p></p>
```

And I also found out that all the statements are executed anyway:

```
(console.log('test'), console.log('test2'), console.log('test3'), 6)
```

Will log:

```
test
test2
test3
```

And the result will be 6.

However, I've also found that some statements can't be used:

```
(throw new Error(), 10)         => SyntaxError: Unexpected token throw
(if (1) console.log('test'), 5) => SyntaxError: Unexpected token if
```

So, what is the point of this parenthesis-comma notation? You could easily execute all the statements and then use the last statement's value. What is this for? Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: A number of languages work this way; Scala works this way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, what is the point of doing this though? I don't understand why you can't just execute all of the statements.

Comment: The `throw` seems obvious.  The second example suggests that the list only accepts basic expressions, not complex code constructs.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: @Ian oh, thanks! If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: `34892` and `console.log('test')` are _expressions_, `if` and `throw` are _statements_. You can apply operators (including the comma operator) to expressions, but not to statements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is the comma operator :)

It lets you evaluate expressions from left to right, returning the last operand's result (which, in your case, isn't stored anywhere, and is perfectly valid).

Reference:

- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: The question already says most of this, though. To repeat from the original question: "You could easily execute all the statements and then use the last statement's value. What is this for?" That question still stands for me. What advantage is there over simply executing statements line by line? Is it just to help write code that takes less space, or is there some revelation here I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious point of this is to allow for multiple expressions in a for loop:

```
for (let x=3, y=6; x < 10; x++, y++) {...}
                           ^^^^^^^^
```

That's the comma operator, the same operator that also allows for the examples you provided

```
return (x, y)
```