# Why does a = (b=3,c=7) assign 7 to a in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I came across an interesting thing in javascript. The following code prints 7.

```
    a = (b=3 , c=7);
    document.write(a);
```

I would like to know how/why this happens.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282879/what-is-the-point-of-wrapping-javascript-statements-in-parentheses

Comment: c = 7 is assigned to a.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator please see this

Comment: @manikantgautam I got that... I wanted to know why..